# Editable combobox overwrites my context menu

Tags: wpf, combobox, contextmenu

I implemented a editable `ComboBox` with XAML which should show my own context menu:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True"
          ContextMenu="{StaticResource contextMenu}"
          ContextMenuClosing="contextClosing">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Item1" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Item2" />
</ComboBox>
```

but instead of showing my context menu, it shows the edit context menu (with Cut, Copy & Paste).

Is there a way to overwrite the editable context menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textbox of the editable part must be loaded to overwrite the standard context menu:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" ContextMenuService.ShowOnDisabled="True" 
     Name="combobox" Loaded="combobox_Loaded">
     <ComboBox.ContextMenu>
         <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="test"></MenuItem>
         </ContextMenu>
     </ComboBox.ContextMenu>
     <ComboBoxItem Content="Item1"></ComboBoxItem>
     <ComboBoxItem Content="Item2"></ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>  

 private void combobox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(combobox, 0), 2) as TextBox).ContextMenu = combobox.ContextMenu;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

2021 and it is still an issue! Excellent observation by dontcare, the combobox does have to be loaded to modify parts of it. However, rather than navigating the visual tree, you can access the textbox portion as;

```
private TextBox cmbTextBox 
{ 
   get { return GetTemplateChild("PART_EditableTextBox") as TextBox; }
}
```